# How can I redirect my homepage to a random url through firebase hosting?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-hosting

I am trying to redirect my homepage with 302 redirect using firebase hosting.

```
"redirects" :[{
    "source": "/",
    "destination": "what do i put here?",
    "type": 302

    }
]
```

In my public folder, I have the index.html, 404.html, and a folder full of files.
I would like for my homepage to randomly redirect to one of those files.

I know you can redirect in the index.html with location.href/assign/replace, but I have to do it through 302 redirect.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible alternative solution, involving Cloud Functions:

In firebase.json

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "function": "randomRedirect"
    }
  ]
}
```

In index.ts of your functions (assuming TypeScript):

```
export const randomRedirect = functions.https.onRequest((_, res: functions.Response) => {
    res.redirect(302, 'your desired URL');
});
```

Edit: You *need* to remove your index.html file for the URL to change in the address bar.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I tested it out and I forgot to mention this, but is there any way to obtain a different random url each time the page is refreshed? The code redirects to a random url, but doesn't change on refresh.

Comment: I see. Maybe it has to do with cache. I'm not sure, I've never done this with a 302, but you can try adding `res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=0, s-maxage=0');` before the `res.redirect`.

Comment: You can also try to rewrite to `"function": "randomRedirect?random=please"` and redeploy functions and hosting.

Comment: sorry, your above code was correct in terms of showing the content of those urls. (I called the random function in a variable outside the export function) But I need to change the url with the redirect. Which isn't happening because I assume its a function in the rewrites attribute of hosting. Any thoughts?

Comment: by above code I meant your original answer, you don't need to change anything. So now when i go to my homepage, the content is random(which is desired), but the link is the same(which is not).

Comment: I see. Are you redirecting to the full URL of your random page? Like `"https://app.web.app/page1.html"`? Does directly visiting the URL of a page show its URL in the browser?

Comment: yeah, the function pulls pages of existing urls. I can visit the random pages by themselves as well

Comment: This is weird. I just did something similar and it works. Check https://us-central1-savage-servers.cloudfunctions.net/playersVsTime , it should return one of page1.html / page2.html / page3.html every time, and I can see it in the address bar. Do you see the URL too? My code is `const rnd = Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 3); res.redirect(302, baseUrl + 'page' + rnd +'.html');`

Comment: Wow, you're right. Did you have any redirects in your firebase.json?

Comment: No. Do you? Did you find your problem?

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, I left the index.html in which probably kept the url constant. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @htmlnoob42069 you mean the index.html file in your files? Or a redirect with it?

Comment: the file in the public folder, I have no redirects attribute